# ng-bind="name" doesn't work inside ckeditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ckeditor

I'm pretty new to Angularjs and I'm trying to echo the value which I type in the input field and expect that to appear in the below div tag where cdkeditor id assigned to it. It seems to work fine without id="editor1" but it doesn't work when I add it.

```
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.6.1/full-all/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="">
<p>Name: <input type="text" ng-model="name"></p>
<div id="editor1">
    <h1>Hello <span ng-bind="name"></span></h1>

</div>
</div>

<script>
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
    toolbar: [
        { name: 'document', items: [ 'Print' ] },
        { name: 'clipboard', items: [ 'Undo', 'Redo' ] }
    ]
} );
</script>
```

Comment: What you are wanting to do  is not trivial. The editor won't compile angular directives on it's own. Why would you need it to include angular directives in the first place?

Answer (score 3):

Try below code you will get input value into CKEditor. You can keep watch on your input scope variable and whenever your input value get changed it will display that text into CKEditor. So, you have to call function `CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.setData($scope.name);` inside watch for setting new input value to CKEditor. Here is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ashishpce2007/m3429wtw/) example.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.6.1/full-all/ckeditor.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<p>Name: <input type="text" ng-model="name"></p>
<div id="editor1">
    <h1>Hello <span ng-bind="name"></span></h1>

</div>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
    toolbar: [
        { name: 'document', items: [ 'Print' ] },
        { name: 'clipboard', items: [ 'Undo', 'Redo' ] }
    ]
} );

$scope.$watch('name', function () {
    CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.setData($scope.name);
});

});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Ashish, but this replaces the "Hello" text. I want it to be incremented.

Comment: @user2672112 : So, in that case you can concat Hello text to $scope.name variable while calling setData function inside watch or you can start your input with Hello if you don't want to concat. Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

For dynamic binding of data in editor field use combination of ckEditor with angular js.

https://github.com/esvit/ng-ckeditor

Take a look in the documentation of ng-ckeditor.

Answer (score 0):

You must use angular-ckeditor.js

html file:

```
<script src="angular.js"></script>
<script src="ckeditor.js"></script>
<script src="angular-ckeditor.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <p>Name: <input type="text" ng-model="name"></p>
    <div id="editor1" ckeditor="options" ng-model="name"></div>

</div>

<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
        CKEDITOR.replace('editor1', {
            toolbar: [
                { name: 'document', items: ['Print'] },
                { name: 'clipboard', items: ['Undo', 'Redo'] }
            ]
        });
        $scope.options = {
            language: "en",
            allowedContent: true,
            entities: false
        };
    });
</script>
```